# Marketing Cloud ampscript with SubscriberAttributes

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to attach a file with [AttachFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attachfile.htm) AMPScript but looks like I'm missing something.

here is my code:

```
%%[
  set @billingUrl = RequestParameter("billingUrl")
]%%

<!-- it works, but I need the request params value --> 
%%= AttachFile('HTTP', 'http://example.com/static-url.pdf') =%%

<!-- it doesn't work and do not send emails -->
%%= AttachFile('HTTP', v(@billingUrl), 'fatura.pdf') =%%
or 
%%= AttachFile('HTTP', @billingUrl, 'fatura.pdf') =%%
or 
%%= AttachFile('HTTP', {{billingUrl}}, 'fatura.pdf') =%%


<!-- it works -->
url: %%=v(@billingUrl)=%%  

<!-- it works -->
url: {{billingUrl}}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: do you have attachments enabled on your account?

Comment: @Data_Kid yes man! It's available. I've updated the example showing what works.

Comment: How are you passing the billing url to the page? `%%= AttachFile('HTTP', v(@billingUrl), 'fatura.pdf') =%%` wont work as that how you call the value of a variable from outside the block not within it

Comment: Try putting the variable in quotes e. g `%%= AttachFile('HTTP', '@billingUrl', 'fatura.pdf') =%%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are looking for the answer, I've found this way to make it works.

```
%%
  [
    Var @billingUrl
    Set @billingUrl = TreatAsContent('{{billingUrl}}')
  ]
%%

%%=AttachFile('HTTP', @billingUrl)=%%
```

Looks like `RequestParameter("billingUrl")` didn't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

You might want to enable the AttachFile ampscript via account manager. This is a paid feature and is charged per 1000 attachments.

Please refer to this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attachfile.htm)

Thanks

Chandan

Comment: It's available. I've updated the example showing what works.